# Patlak equation

Tags: arithmetic, biology

For solute flux across microvessel wall, these two equations are supposed to be equivalent:

$$
\begin{align}
J_s &= J_v(1-\sigma_f)\frac{C_i - C_Le^{\mathrm{Pe}}}{1 - e^{\mathrm{Pe}}} \\
J_s &= J_v(1- \sigma_f) \left( C_L - \frac{\Delta C}{1 - e^{\mathrm{Pe}}}\right) 
\end{align}
$$

where $ \Delta C = C_L - C_i $ and Pe is the Peclet number.

But how? It should be obvious, but I don't see it. I'm hoping it's just a mathematical argument that I'm missing, so somebody can enlighten me without the physical background.

Comment: One way to check that the two statements agree is that, if the Peclet number is very negative, then they give $C_i$ and $C_L-\Delta C$ which are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{C_i-C_Le^{Pe}}{1-e^{Pe}}=\frac{C_i-C_Le^{Pe}+C_L-C_L}{1-e^{Pe}}=\frac{C_L(1-e^{Pe})-(C_L-C_i)}{1-e^{Pe}}$$
$$=C_L-\frac{(C_L-C_i)}{1-e^{Pe}}=C_L-\frac{\Delta C}{1-e^{Pe}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$C_L=\frac{C_L(1-e^{Pe})}{1-e^{Pe}}$